# Z direction UIView rotating?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, quartz-2d

I am using following code for rotating z direction the UIView. It rotates in right side. But I want to rotate bottom side instead of right side (as it is in right side).

```
UIView *myView = self.view;
CALayer *layer = myView.layer;

CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
transform.m34 = 1.0 / -2000;

CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -500;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, 45.0f * M_PI / 180.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked at the parameters the `CATransform3DRotate` function takes?

The last three elements define the vector the view will flip around. Your vector is parallel to the y axis. Try this instead for the rotation around a vertical axis.

```
 rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(
            rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, 
            45.0f * M_PI / 180.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

You might need to change the anchor point to get the axis on the right "height".